# Upgrading from FreeForm v3.0.6 to v4.1.3

Tags: solspace-freeform

I just upgraded from v3.0.6 to v4.1.3. I have 8 forms that were created using v3.0.6 that seem to be still working. Can I leave them as is, even though the use some outdated parameter names?